# Java Jar File Graphics are Not Showing Up

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I have created a simple graphics program(LIKE VERY SIMPLE). It worked all fine when I ran the class file, but when I simply created a JAR file (executable), nothing ran. Could I please get a bit of help with this. Thanks. I compiled it normally in the cmd, with the command "**jar -cf Graphics.jar Graphics.class Render.class icon.png"**

**Graphics.java:**

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Graphics extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Graphics() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.add(new Render());
        window.setTitle("Example of Graphics in JAVA");
        ClassLoader ldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL imager = ldr.getResource("./icon.png");
        String path = imager.getPath();
        File f = new File(path);
        File imageicon = f;
        Image im = null;
        try {
            im = ImageIO.read(imageicon);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        window.setIconImage(im);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graphics g = new Graphics();
    }
}
```

**Render.java:**

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Render extends JPanel{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graph) {
        super.paintComponent(graph);
        this.setBackground(Color.blue);
        graph.setColor(Color.red);
        graph.fillArc(0,0, 400, 400, 0, 360);
    }
}
```

**There is also an  image called "icon.png"**

Comment: By the way, Eclipse IDE compiled it and it ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `File`:

```
im = ImageIO.read(imageicon);
```

Back to the `URL`:

```
im = ImageIO.read(imager);
```

As an embedded resource (in the Jar) it is no longer a `File`.